# Navigation in Jetpack Compose: "cannot find a parameter with this name: startDestination" for the NavHost class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

My current question is about why does the error message in the title appears? I am following a tutorial on youtube of Plillip Lackner, trying to understand how navigation between multiple screens can be implemented, and checked if I have the same updated dependencies and it seems like they are correct. However I get this error message and I have a bit of a hard time figuring out what is wrong in how I configured the project. Any advice would help. My guess is that it is probably about a difference between different versions of the class.

[image]

And this is the app build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.navigationforbeginners"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.navigationforbeginners"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1") //
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0") //
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.2")//
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.6.1") //
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.6.2") //
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.6.2") //
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also provide the `builder` parameter, the last parameter that you use to map routes to screens.

Just add that parameter by adding an empty pair of curly braces after the closing parenthesis, like this:

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.MainScreen.route) {

}
```

Now the compiler can recognize what `NavHost` function you want to call and also accepts the `startDestination` parameter.